# how to properly handle promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

In my Angular app, I'm using $odataresource for data retrieval and updates.

I have the following lines:

```
var measure = $odataresource("http://windows-10:8888/ChangeMeasure/");

            var myMeasure = measure.odata().filter("ID",$scope.ngData[index].ID)
                .single();
```

I, then, need to issue an update on myMeasure:

```
myMeasure.$update();
```

The trouble is - when I issue $update, myMeasure is still an unresolved promise.

What is the proper syntax to call `myMeasure.$update();` when `myMeasure` promise is resolved?

Comment: `measure.then(function(){myMeasure.$update()})`

Comment: TypeError: measure.then is not a function

Comment: `.single(function(){myMeasure.$update()})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of [ODataAngularResources](https://github.com/devnixs/ODataAngularResources) try the following:

```
  var measure = $odataresource("http://windows-10:8888/ChangeMeasure/");
  var myMeasure = measure.odata().filter("ID",$scope.ngData[index].ID)
                  .query(function(data){
                    data[0].$update(); 
                    console.log("Everything went ok!")
                   },function(){
                    console.log("Oops, something wrong happened!")
                   });
```

Of course some more thought should go into sending the resource.update directly after receiving it.

Comment: TypeError: measure.$odata is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109961/discussion-between-bananenmannfrau-and-eugene-goldberg).